# Comma Placement When Using The Word "Though"

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas

Should there be a comma before the word "though?"

Example:

I am currently working with a content writer though it would be good to find more options.

Answer (score -1):

[This source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/though_1) shows that though is a conjunction.

[This source](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37856/do-you-need-a-comma-before-a-subordinating-conjunction-like-if) explains whether to use a comma or not. If a subordination conjunction begins the sentence, you need to use a comma. Otherwise, you don't.