# Dashes usage for additional explanation after or before a comma?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas

So, here is the sentence I'm trying to write:

They got to know our business through many different venues - through actually just people they knew, through consulting companies - but I think the most important aspect...

Now, should I put the comma right after "venues" or after the dashes?
They got to know our business through many different venues, - through actually just people they knew, through consulting companies - but I think the most important aspect...
OR
They got to know our business through many different venues - through actually just people they knew, through consulting companies -, but I think the most important aspect...

Or I don't need it at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I write a comma followed by an em-dash?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131874/can-i-write-a-comma-followed-by-an-em-dash) and [How is punctuation used after dashes?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9816/how-is-punctuation-used-after-dashes) and [em-dash and comma, which comes first](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134031/em-dash-and-comma-which-comes-first).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Punctuation doesn't have rules per se but guidelines to improve the reader's flow and comprehension.

Your use of two em-dashes seems perfectly fine without a comma.

However, there are extraneous words which slow your readers down and your *through ... through* construction distorts the comprehension. It's fine for a speech where the speaker would know where to pause. How about

**They get to know our business through different venues—primarily through people they know and consulting companies—but the most important aspect …**

Or, don't try to fit it all into one sentence.

**They get to know our business through multiple venues: it's the people they know and the consulting companies. But the most important aspect …**

Note elimination of phrases like *I think* in an opinion piece; we know it's your opinion. Also, pick a tense and go with it.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't modify the sentence because it's an audio file I'm trying to transcribe. But thanks for the answer!

Comment: Ah, that makes sense; it sounds verbal. Two em-dashes, no comma

Answer (score 2):

Typically, the "dash" you're looking for is represented by two dashes, or more properly by the actual em dash character, where that is available. Since the dash indicates a break in the thought of the sentence, a comma (which does something similar, but not as strongly) isn't necessary. When the break occurs between two clauses, there's no need to add a comma in addition.

Answer (score 0):

To omit the *comma* would violate the rule on coordinating conjunctions (*and*/*but*/*or*), which mandates that a comma will separate the two independent clauses. The violation is sure to give some readers a feeling akin to that of stepping off an airport moving walkway: **They get to know our business through different venues—primarily through people they know and consulting companies—but the most important aspect…**

In this particular example, the clear fix is to replace the ***second*** *em-dash* with a *period*: **They get to know our business through different venues — primarily through people they know and consulting companies. But the most important aspect...**

However, not every example can be so easily adjusted. Had the second clause been a subordinate, we would feel compelled, on the one hand, to set it off with a **single** *comma*. And, on the other, to retain ***both*** *em-dashes*, in order to point out the parenthetical. The pressure to apply both rules would be irresistible.

And the jury is still out on it: [Does the em-dash replace a subordinating comma?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/342883/does-the-em-dash-replace-a-subordinating-comma)

Comment: The ['It is mandatory to use a comma before a coordinating conjunction uniting the two independent clauses in a compound sentence'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9239/is-it-mandatory-to-use-a-comma-before-a-coordinating-conjunction-uniting-the-two) 'rule' has been discussed here, and relegated to 'generally true, but with sensible exceptions' status.